# If I wanted to save uploaded files in '/usr/local' using my grails app, do i need to grant permissions?

Tags: grails

I have an app the moves uploaded files to a certain location in my drive like so:

```
def storagePathDirectory = new File(destinationPath)

        if(!storagePathDirectory.exists()) {
            log.info("Storage Path Directory does not exist. Creating a new directory: ${storagePathDirectory.toString()} ...")
            if (storagePathDirectory.mkdirs()){
                log.info("Successfully created: ${storagePathDirectory.toString()}")
            } else {
                log.info("Failed to create: ${storagePathDirectory.toString()}...")
            }
        }
```

I wanted to save under `/usr/local/something/something`. It works great if the the app tried to move the file in a folder that's not restricted like `/home/user/something`. Do I need to set permissions for my app so that it could write files under `/usr/`? How do I do this with grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you will need to grant permissions to the target direction on the host OS. These permissions should be as restrictive as possible. Allowing for read and write for the account which Tomcat (or whatever container you are using to run your WAR) is running under.

The issue you are going to have is typically /usr/ doesn't allow that account access to it. Therefore your application itself can't change the permissions. This is going to have to be done by the administrator of the server.

Again, **be as restrictive as possible with your permissions**. Don't simply chmod -R 777 for everyone. Please at least consider 770.

Comment: Do you think `'sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/something'` is good enough? I tried it and it worked, but not sure if it's restrictive enough..

Comment: I would suggest you look at the permissions that are granted when you do that. I suspect it will be 'good enough'. (ls -l)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the problem is OS permission,

You have to use:

> chmod -R 777 /usr/local/something/something

and could be great, but it's not reasonable from security perspective